# Searching for unwanted values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Python beginner here! I'm trying to create a simple program for grading students (in the danish grading system, I know it's weird). So this is my dataframe with the students and their grades for each assignment, and I want to be able to search the assignment columns for unwanted values. The values I want to keep are 12, 10, 7, 4, 2, 0 and -3.

```
   StudentID              Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
0    s123456  Michael Andersen            7            7            4
1    s123789  Bettina Petersen           12           11           10
2    s123468    Thomas Nielsen           -3            7            2
3    s123579      Marie Hansen            0            2            2
4    s123588     Amalie Jensen           10            5            7
5    s123588     Amalie Jensen           10            7            7
6    s123540    Helena Bentsen           10           10           12
7    s123019      Bent Knudsen            4            4            4
8    s123019  Mattias Kjeldsen            4            4           20 
9    s120079     Robert Madsen            4            7           10
10   s129834     Robert Madsen           12           12           12
11   s120068    Camilla Madsen            7            7           10
```

The rows with unwanted values should be displayed like this:

```
   StudentID              Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
1    s123789  Bettina Petersen           12           11           10
4    s123588     Amalie Jensen           10            5            7
8    s123019  Mattias Kjeldsen            4            4           20
```

(Btw. I'm aware of the duplicates, but I know how to take care of that.) 
This dataframe is just an example, and the method should work on dataframes with any number of assignments and students. I don't know how to proceed. Help :(

Comment: Perhaps try the Pandas function `isin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way with `.isin`. Steps:

1. Store values that you want to keep.
2. Mark columns that contain grades.
3. Check if each entry in each grade column is a value that you want to keep `df[asmt_cols].isin(values_to_keep)`.
4. Mark rows that have only the desired values: `df[asmt_cols].isin(values_to_keep).all(1)`.
5. Negate with `~` and filter.

---

```
values_to_keep = [12, 10, 7, 4, 2, 0, -3]
asmt_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("Assignment")]

unwanted = df[~df[asmt_cols].isin(values_to_keep).all(1)]

# Out[99]:
# StudentID      Name  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3
# 1 s123789   Bettina  Petersen           12           11           10
# 4 s123588    Amalie    Jensen           10            5            7
# 8 s123019   Mattias  Kjeldsen            4            4           20
```